# Find whether a column is in pascal case or not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make pascal casing for a column, for this I have written a function which does the job. But running the function even for the records which are already in pascal casing may kill time. I want to check if a record is already in Pascal case and if not apply function on it.

I tried as below...

```
select col1 from table1 
where col1 <> dbo.fn_PascalCase(col1)
```

I was expecting to see records that are not pascal case'ed. But no benefits

Comment: Which is collation of the `col1` column? Is it case sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is simple. Need to add `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` at the end.

Below is giving appropriate result

```
select col1 from table1 
where col1 <> dbo.fn_PascalCase(col1)
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```